# How connect a Ruby on Rails written website with android app with same data base hosted on Heroku which uses Postgresql

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

hello I am Kashif I made a website with ruby on rails and now I wanted to make an android app and I want to use a single database for both website and app, I hosted the website on Heroku and Heroku uses the Postgresql, so how could I connect them Please help me

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to create an API for your RoR application. Your android application can communicate with your website through this API. You can create the API on a different namespace which will leave your website unaffected. [This article](https://labs.kollegorna.se/blog/2015/04/build-an-api-now/) will have you started on how to create an API for your application.

Comment: thanks, can you tell how could i make APIs

Comment: I have added a link to an article that shows how to create an API.

Answer (score 0):

You should create web services to read/write data in your rails application.

Call the webservices from android app

Answer (score 0):

Just create another rails app only for web services(use same db) or you can add web-services in exiting app and use by android app.

you can use rails api gem https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api